# Generate diff JSON

Tags: javascript, json, diff

I'm trying to create a function that will do a deep comparison of two JSON objects (objectA vs. objectB).  And then generate a unique JSON object that only has the node tree to different data values.

My idea was to ship parts of the JSON into a recursive function, coupled with an array that held the data path.  But when I run the code as I have it written, I am getting extra elements in my path array.

The end result ideally will provide a path like:
`[ "level1c", "level2b", "level3c" ]`
but unfortunately I am getting:
`[ "level1a", "level1b", "level1c", "level2b", "level3c" ]`

Once, I had a solid data path, then I was going to take that to build a new JSON object that **only** includes the nodes that differ.

```
function compareJSON( primary, secondary ){

    function diffJSON( primary, secondary, path ){

        var p = path.slice(); // copy array

        var keys = Object.keys( secondary );
        var sVal;
        var pVal;

        for( var i=0, x=keys.length; i<x; i++ ){

            sVal = secondary[keys[i]];
            pVal = primary[keys[i]];

            if( sVal !== pVal ){
                p.push( keys[i] );
                if( typeof sVal === 'object' && !Array.isArray( sVal ) ){
                    diffJSON( pVal, sVal, p );
                }else{
                    if( Array.isArray( sVal ) ){
                        compareArray( sVal, pVal, p );
                    }else{
                        updateResult( sVal, p );
                    }// END if( !Array.isArray() )
                }// END if( typeof sVal === 'object' ... )
            }// END if( sVal !== pVal )

        }// END for loop

        function compareArray( arr, arr2, path ){
            // compare arrays
        }

        function updateResult( data, path ){
            console.log( data, path );
        }// END function updateResult()

    }// END function diffJSON()

    diffJSON( primary, secondary, [] );

}// END function compareJSON()
```

Additional info:

- I know that objectA and objectB are both structured the same; wherein objectB will only ever be a modification of the data in objectA.
- Looking for a less than ES6 solution (old browser support fun).
- The primary question is how do I capture the right node path towards differing data; any tips/tricks/comments on how to improve the core code is welcome but not really the answer.

Here's the code in practice, it prints out into the console a value that's found to be different in json2 (compared to json1) and the associated path array:

```js
'use strict';

function compareJSON( primary, secondary ){

 function diffJSON( primary, secondary, path ){

  var p = path.slice(); // copy array
  
  var keys = Object.keys( secondary );
  var sVal;
  var pVal;

  for( var i=0, x=keys.length; i<x; i++ ){
   
   sVal = secondary[keys[i]];
   pVal = primary[keys[i]];

   if( sVal !== pVal ){
    p.push( keys[i] );
    if( typeof sVal === 'object' && !Array.isArray( sVal ) ){
     diffJSON( pVal, sVal, p );
    }else{
     if( Array.isArray( sVal ) ){
      compareArray( sVal, pVal, p );
     }else{
      updateResult( sVal, p );
     }// END if( !Array.isArray() )
    }// END if( typeof sVal === 'object' ... )
   }// END if( sVal !== pVal )
      
  }// END for loop

  function compareArray( arr, arr2, path ){
   var match = true;
   for( var i=0, x=arr.length; i<x; i++ ){
    if( arr[i] !== arr2[i] ){
     match = false;
    }
   }
   if( !match ){
    updateResult( arr, path );
   }
  }
  
  function updateResult( data, path ){
   console.log( data, path );
  }// END function updateResult()

  
  
 }// END function diffJSON()

 diffJSON( primary, secondary, [] );
 
}// END function compareJSON()

var json1 = {
 level1a : {
  level2a : {
   level3a : 'apple',
   level3b : ['happy', 'happy', 'joy', 'joy'],
   level3c : {
    level4a : 'sleep'
   },
   level3d : true
  },
  level2b : 'music',
  level2c : {
   level3a : 'future',
   level3b : false,
   level3c : ['bear', 'camel', 'elephant']
  }
 },
 level1b : {
  level2a : 'jeopardy',
  level2b : 10200,
  level2c : true,
  level2d : {
   level3a : 'aliens',
   level3b : 'weekend'
  }
 },
 level1c : {
  level2a : 'fiber',
  level2b : [1, 2, 4, 5, 6]
 },
 level1d : ['apple', 'cat', 'baby'],
 level1e : true,
 level1f : {
  level2a : false,
  level2b : true,
  level2c : {
   level3a : 'naruto',
   level3b : 123,
   level3c : 'test',
   level3d : 'this',
   level3e : 'thing'
  },
  level2d : true
 }
};

var json2 = {
 level1a : {
  level2a : {
   level3a : 'apple',
   level3b : ['happy', 'happy', 'joy', 'joy'],
   level3c : {
    level4a : 'sleep'
   },
   level3d : true
  },
  level2b : 'music',
  level2c : {
   level3a : 'future',
   level3b : false,
   level3c : ['bear', 'camel', 'elephant', 'lion']
  }
 },
 level1b : {
  level2a : 'jeopardy',
  level2b : 10200,
  level2c : true,
  level2d : {
   level3a : 'ancient',
   level3b : 'weekend'
  }
 },
 level1c : {
  level2a : 'fiber',
  level2b : [1, 2, 4, 5, 6]
 },
 level1d : ['apple', 'cat', 'baby'],
 level1e : true,
 level1f : {
  level2a : false,
  level2b : true,
  level2c : {
   level3a : 'naruto',
   level3b : 123,
   level3c : 'spicy',
   level3d : 'this',
   level3e : 'thing'
  },
  level2d : true
 }
};

compareJSON( json1, json2 );
```

Thanks for your time and support :)

Comment: In terms of equality, what do you define that as for your diffJSON? i.e. if a key/value pair had true/false vs a stringified 'true'/'false', should your diffJSON know to consider those are unequal?

Comment: Ideally, yes, if it was a boolean vs. a string, it should assume different values.

Comment: will your array be pure or can it contain mixed values of strings, objects etc?

Comment: the array will only contain string values.  the array order matters as well; so that's why there's just a basic loop of arr1[index] vs. arr2[index]

Comment: Here is a link to a gist that will diff objects but it uses Ramda.js so may not apply but you may be able to get some inspiration from it. https://gist.github.com/plukevdh/dec4b41d5b7d67f83be630afecee499e

Answer (score 1):

I've modified your code a little bit to split the variable that hold the path and array that hold all diffs.

I am assuming both structure are equivalent, otherwise you would need to do an intersect and diff on keys of a and b, print diffs separately and loop on intersect.

I am using ***Object.prototype.toString*** so that in future you might add more cases (switch case friendly if you wanna go that route) and to reduce the checks.

```js
      //if you want you pass allDiffs and path here and enhance this function to print array positional diff also 
    var isEqualArrays = function compareArray( arr1, arr2 ){
               if(arr1.length !== arr2.length) return false;
       var match = true;
       for( var i=0, x=arr1.length; i<x; i++ ){
        if( arr1[i] !== arr2[i] ){
         match = false;
        }
       }
       return match;
      }
var toString = Object.prototype.toString;
    
function compare (a, b, allDiffs, previousPath) {
      var akeys = Object.keys(a);
      for (key of akeys) {
        var currentPath = previousPath.concat(key);
        var typeOfa = toString.call(a[key]);
        var typeOfb = toString.call(b[key]);
        if(typeOfa !== typeOfb) {
           allDiffs.push({path: currentPath, values: [a[key], b[key]] })
           continue
        }
        if(typeOfa === '[object Array]')  {
            if(!isEqualArrays(a[key], b[key])){//remove this if , if you want enhance route
               allDiffs.push({path: currentPath, values: [a[key], b[key]] })
            }
           continue;
         }
         if(typeOfa === '[object Object]') {
           compare(a[key], b[key], allDiffs, currentPath)
           continue
         }
         if(a[key] !== b[key]) {
            allDiffs.push({path: currentPath, values: [a[key], b[key]] })
         }
      }
    
      return allDiffs
 }
    
    var json1 = {
     level1a : {
      level2a : {
       level3a : 'apple',
       level3b : ['happy', 'happy', 'joy', 'joy'],
       level3c : {
        level4a : 'sleep'
       },
       level3d : true
      },
      level2b : 'music',
      level2c : {
       level3a : 'future',
       level3b : false,
       level3c : ['bear', 'camel', 'elephant']
      }
     },
     level1b : {
      level2a : 'jeopardy',
      level2b : 10200,
      level2c : true,
      level2d : {
       level3a : 'aliens',
       level3b : 'weekend'
      }
     },
     level1c : {
      level2a : 'fiber',
      level2b : [1, 2, 4, 5, 6]
     },
     level1d : ['apple', 'cat', 'baby'],
     level1e : true,
     level1f : {
      level2a : false,
      level2b : true,
      level2c : {
       level3a : 'naruto',
       level3b : 123,
       level3c : 'test',
       level3d : 'this',
       level3e : 'thing'
      },
      level2d : true
     }
    };
    
    var json2 = {
     level1a : {
      level2a : {
       level3a : 'apple',
       level3b : ['happy', 'happy', 'joy', 'joy'],
       level3c : {
        level4a : 'sleep'
       },
       level3d : true
      },
      level2b : 'music',
      level2c : {
       level3a : 'future',
       level3b : false,
       level3c : ['bear', 'camel', 'elephant', 'lion']
      }
     },
     level1b : {
      level2a : 'jeopardy',
      level2b : 10200,
      level2c : true,
      level2d : {
       level3a : 'ancient',
       level3b : 'weekend'
      }
     },
     level1c : {
      level2a : 'fiber',
      level2b : [1, 2, 4, 5, 6]
     },
     level1d : ['apple', 'cat', 'baby'],
     level1e : true,
     level1f : {
      level2a : false,
      level2b : true,
      level2c : {
       level3a : 'naruto',
       level3b : 123,
       level3c : 'spicy',
       level3d : 'this',
       level3e : 'thing'
      },
      level2d : true
     }
    };
    
    console.log(compare(json1, json2, [], []))
```